# Does Mozilla/5.0 in the User-Agent field signify the browser is HTML5 capable?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, user-agent, mozilla

Can it be assumed that a browser that indicates `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible...)` is HTML5 capable?

Comment: Translation tip: in this construction, the word "mean" is more appropriate than "signify". Not always the literal translation ("signify" is the literal translation from my language, too) is the right one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You should use something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect features and fallback where necessary.

HTML5 is a collection of different features, so you should check for the browser features you want. The User-Agent field shouldn't be used for determining compatibility, since the client program can lie about that. User-Agent sniffing is not a recommended way to determine compatibility -- it's too error-prone, and there are multiple browsers that have ways of changing the User-Agent field to appear as other browsers.

The reason that the Mozilla/5.0 or Mozilla/4.0 shows up in User-Agent for so many browsers is to show that they have backward compatibility with some version of Netscape (4.0 = Netscape 4.0 -- 5.0 is compatible with the original suite (aka SeaMonkey)). Basically every browser out there will claim this compatibility, so it's not a very useful indicator.

Comment: I understand that, but you could weed out very old browsers by checking if it's no less than Mozilla/5.0. Then for 5.0 do more fine-grained feature tests.

Comment: @mojuba: That part of the user agent string has absolutely no meaning, it's a tribute to backwards compatibility with Netscape 4.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant so there is still no answer as to why non-Mozilla browsers use this version string and what they mean by 4.0 or 5.0 for example.

Comment: @mojuba: As I said, it's about backwards compatibility. But you could also try googling or just reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Format).

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't use headers to check for HTML5 compatibility, just let the browser do it: send both HTML5 and HTML<5 content, and do some hacks to show them in the proper cases. For example:

```
<audio>Username:</audio><input type="text" placeholder="Username">
```

In this case, if possible, use the `placeholder`, else show a label. The content in the `<audio>...</audio>` will be shown by non-HTML5 browsers, while HTML5 browsers will ignore it; vice versa, non-HTML5 browsers won't parse the `placeholder="Username"`, while HTML5 browsers will.